# How to update instead of rewriting csv by python with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Every day I'm scraping a CSV file from the web and updating a CSV file in my system.
How do I update the CSV file? I don't want to create a new CSV file every day, I just need to update one CSV file?. Before that, I need to remove previous days data so that I don't have duplicate data in CSV.

Comment: What have you tried, what code do you have to read the csv and remove duplicates?

Comment: You can open file in "append" mode so that it add new lines at the end of the file, is that what you want?

Comment: How do I open it in append mode?. my file name is file.csv I have data frame df to append it to file.csv. But since the file.csv already has data till previous day. My data frame has additional data for today. How do I do that?

Comment: I have been using excel so far. but currently, it exceeded the row number lmit. So I'm switching to csv.

Comment: writer = pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
This is the code I used to update the excel sheet